# Setting x-axis as dates using mdates with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm loading these packages:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
sns.set()
%matplotlib inline
```

And I have a dataframe `df` which looks like this

```
df['element_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['element_date'])
df['mdate'] = [mdates.date2num(d) for d in df['element_date']]
df.head()

id            Tier    element     element_date           mdate
5228039     Tier B      4      2018-05-28 10:59:00  736842.457639
5232263     Tier B      3      2018-05-28 10:59:00  736842.457639
5245478     Tier B      EA     2018-05-27 13:58:00  736841.581944
4975552     Tier B      2      2018-05-30 21:01:00  736844.875694
4975563     Tier A      2      2018-05-30 21:01:00  736844.875694
```

I'm trying to set the x axis of a count-plot to month and day only, and I'm getting an error message. This is the code I'm running (I've removed the naming labels to save space):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
fig = sns.countplot(x="mdate", hue="element", data=df)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
plt.show(fig)
```

I'm getting `DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date.  This usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()`

Now, of course I've tried adding `ax.xaxis_date()`, to no avail. I also have no x values that are equal to 0. I've dropped NA, and value counted mdate, and there is no 0 to be found.

I've looked at a bunch of different answers here, and can't seem to get to a solution. I've tried both using `element_date` as my date time value, as well as using "mathplotlib" dates using `mdate`.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Essentially, I'm just trying to have my x-axis be an ordered series of dates over two months, with elements being counted for each date.

Thanks!

Comment: `countplot` is a categorical plot. Category 0 is `736841.581944`, category 1 is `736842.457639` etc. So you cannot use a dateformatter on the axes which consists of `0,1,2,3 etc`. I suppose if you want to have dates on the axes you want a numeric bar plot? In that case use `plt.bar`.

Comment: Interesting, however, when I make a barplot using the same data, I can set my x-value as mdate, but as soon as I try to format it with: `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))`, I get the same error message.

Comment: Nah, you cannot get this error message when using `plt.bar`, unless you also try to plot something else in the same axes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buried down on a GitHub pandas issues page, user, @pawaller, found a [workaround](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1918#issuecomment-297019907) using `plt.FixedFormatter` where you string format the datetime dataframe column.

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df['element_date'].dt.strftime("%m-%d")))
```

However, using above does not immediately work as value labels are out of order and not aligned properly. Hence, `unique()` and `sort_values()` are required:

```
x_dates = df['element_date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d').sort_values().unique()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(x_dates))
```

To demonstrate below (where *mdate* column is never used):

**Data**

```
from io import StringIO
...

txt = '''id            Tier    element     element_date           mdate
5228039     "Tier B"      4      "2018-05-28 10:59:00"  736842.457639
5232263     "Tier B"      3      "2018-05-28 10:59:00"  736842.457639
5245478     "Tier B"      EA     "2018-05-27 13:58:00"  736841.581944
4975552     "Tier B"      2      "2018-05-30 21:01:00"  736844.875694
4975563     "Tier A"      2      "2018-05-30 21:01:00"  736844.875694'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", parse_dates=[3])
```

**Plot**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,4))

fig = sns.countplot(x="element_date", hue="element", data=df, ax=ax)

x_dates = df['element_date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d').sort_values().unique()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(x_dates))

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output]